# Print range - print from page x until end of document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, range

Is there any way in Microsoft Word in the print range box to print from page 3 for example to the end of the document without entering the last page number?

I've tried the likes of :

```
12-*
12 onwards
```

Googling has not shed much light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try with the `x-y` syntax without specifying the ending page, for example:

```
12-
```